# Add percentage to variable using cURL

Tags: php, math, variables

How can I add 80% of the value of variable a (it is a numeric value), so when I echo it, it echos with the percentage added?

```
// Include the library
include('simple_html_dom.php');

    $html = file_get_html('https://thecurlurl.com/');

    // Find the DIV tag with an id of "myId"
    foreach($html->find('span#myId') as $a)

    // add 80% to variable "a", how ?
    echo $a->innertext . '<br>';
    echo $a;
```

Comment: ...where is cURL being used in your example?

Comment: By "add 80%", do you mean the value is numeric, or do you want to concatenate the string "80%"... what?

Comment: @Amber: With the include file I have added above.

Comment: @minitech: The vale of "a" is numeric, I want to add 80% of it, to it, then output.

Comment: `echo floatval($a->innertext) * 1.8;`, you mean?

Comment: @minitech: thank you! and echo floatval($a) * 1.8; for the next echo?

Comment: @MartinH23: Isn't `$a->innertext` more appropriate than `$a`, which is an object? I think I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: @minitech: you're absolutely right! just trying some math work on returned values

Comment: I removed the 'curl' tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the comments:

```
echo floatval($a->innertext) * 1.8;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo round( $a/100 * 180 );
```